# Laravel one to many table seed is not seeded as expected

Tags: laravel, laravel-seeding

So I have a relationship table like this [ERD](https://dbdiagram.io/d/64c5362b02bd1c4a5ee815be). I'm using eloquent database relationship in laravel to manage the foreign key.

It worked, but the data added is skipping one row.

[image: Like this]

This is how I seed the database.

```
    public function run(): void
    {

        User::factory()
        ->has(FavPlant::factory(),'fav_Plant')
        ->count(5)
        ->create();
        
        Plants::factory()
        ->has(FavPlant::factory(),'fav_Plant')
        ->count(5)
        ->create();

    }
```

How do I make the relation table have both `user_id` and `plants_id` simultaneously?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have a many-to-many relationship between users and plants through the FavPlant pivot table. You can set both `user_id` and `plant_id` at the same time as below.

```
public function run(): void
{
    $users = User::factory()
        ->count(5)
        ->create();

    $plants = Plants::factory()
        ->count(5)
        ->create();

    // Seed FavPlant pivot table with relationships
    foreach ($users as $user) {
        foreach ($plants as $plant) {
            FavPlant::factory([
                'user_id' => $user->id,
                'plants_id' => $plant->id,
            ])->create();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ohhh so I can use `foreach` for that , Thank you for the answer